# jquery code - alert-message not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a button with id="mybutton".

When clicking the button the alert "test" is supposed to appear.

My js code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $("#mybutton").click(function(){
                    alert("test");
                });
});
```

can anybody explain to me why this code does not work (there's no alert message) ... I just don't get it.

Comment: Have you checked the  console for errors? Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score -1):

ok, I know why: forgot to include jQuery ...

Comment: You should spend more time looking for errors–especially looking into the console–before posting to stackoverflow ;o)